# AWS Hello World C# Lambda function returning Json error

Tags: c#, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using the default AWS Visual Studio template. When I run the test locally and use the AWS Hello World Example Request:

[image]

I get the error:

> System.Exception: Error deserializing the input JSON to type String
> at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src184553615\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 215
> at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ExecutionRequest request) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src184553615\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 52
> ---------------- Inner 1 Exception ------------
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src184553615\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 203
> ---------------- Inner 2 Exception ------------
> Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.JsonSerializerException: Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to a string. JSON strings must be quoted, for example "Hello World" in order to be converted to a string: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
> at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
> ---------------- Inner 3 Exception ------------
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& readStack, Utf8JsonReader& reader, Exception ex)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ParseCore(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options) at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
> ---------------- Inner 4 Exception ------------
> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.
> at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetString()
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterString.Read(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnRead(ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.Read(JsonTokenType tokenType, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)

However, If I use "Hello World" as my input string it runs just fine. I definitely want to use Json for the input. I have validated the AWS Json input and it validates.

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace AWSLambda2
{
    public class Function
    {
        
        /// <summary>
        /// A simple function that takes a string and does a ToUpper
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FunctionHandler(String input, ILambdaContext context)
        {

            return input?.ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

The .csproj file contents:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>

    <!-- This property makes the build directory similar to a publish directory and helps the AWS .NET Lambda Mock Test Tool find project dependencies. -->
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: right now your function accepts a string and not an object. if you send an object to the function in form of a json it trys to deserialize this object into the type of object which your function accepts, in your case a string. But the json object you send isnt a string

Comment: Isparia - That was it!. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The "Error deserializing the input JSON to type String" error message is because the method signature on your `FunctionHandler` specifies `String` but you testing with JSON.

```cs
public string FunctionHandler(String input, ILambdaContext context)
```

If you added code similar to below to define a class matching the structure of that input...

```cs
    public class FunctionInput
    {
        public string Key1 { get; set; }
        public string Key2 { get; set; }
        public string Key3 { get; set; }
    }
```

...then changed your method signature to specify `FunctionInput`...

```cs
public string FunctionHandler(FunctionInput input, ILambdaContext context)
```

...the `LambdaSerializer` would attempt to deserialized the JSON into that class.